# fetch the first item from 1 list in another list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance

I have 2 lists List1 and List2. I'm trying to iterate over list1 and for each element in it, check if any item from list2 is present in it. If yes then populate a dictionary.

```
list1 = ["Item1 Item_1", "Item2 Vs. Item_2", "Item3", "Item4 versus Item_4", "Item5", "Item6 Vs. Item_6"]
list2 = ["Vs.", "versus"]
outDictionary = {"Vs.": ["Item2 Vs. Item_2", "Item6 Vs. Item_6"], "versus": ["Item4 versus Item_4"]}
```

Both list1 and list2 are getting populated from different logic and could be anything. I'm implementing this using 2 for loops. I'm guessing there should be a better way to do this. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Can you show your existing attempt? It's hard to say what's better without a frame of reference. Also, by "better" do you mean more efficient? More Pythonic? [See also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). `{k: [x for x in list1 if k in x] for k in list2}` might be OK from a Pythonic perspective but it's not terribly efficient.

Comment: List comprehension, [(y, x) in xs for y in ys if y in x]. You can make dict out of list of tuples next.

Comment: well! I cant use list comprehension. The actual problem I'm facing is slightly different than what I posted. I'm new and saw somewhere it was not recommended to post the full problem (dont ask contributors to code for you). Thats why I changed it. In reality dictionary is not output.

Comment: By more efiicient, I want to remove one for loop.

Comment: Can someone please upvote the question to remove negative votes. I edited the question and even received the answers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the list1 phrases into a set of words, and list2 into a set of words then populate the dict with any phrase with a word in common with a word from the second list.

**Only timing for your actual data will tell,** but don't be suprised if using the in-built Python data structures are faster and more maintainable than something like a trie implementation written in interpreted Python.

```
In [14]: d2 = set(list2)

In [15]: out = {word: [] for word in list2}

In [16]: for phrase in list1:
    ...:     for common in d2 & set(phrase.split()):
    ...:         out[common].append(phrase)

In [17]: out
Out[17]: 
{'Vs.': ['Item2 Vs. Item_2', 'Item6 Vs. Item_6'],
 'versus': ['Item4 versus Item_4']}

In [18]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this kind of problem.
First turn `list1` into a `Series`

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ["Item1 Item_1", "Item2 Vs. Item_2", "Item3", "Item4 versus Item_4", "Item5", "Item6 Vs. Item_6"]
list2 = ["Vs.", "versus"]

s = pd.Series(list1)

{item: s[s.str.contains(item)].to_list() for item in list2}
```

#### EDIT (based on the comment)

for covering the case you mention is sufficient to change last line like so:

`{item: s[s.str.contains(f' {item} ')].to_list() for item in list2}`

Comment: The example doesn't cover it, but `.contains` may have problems if any word from list2 is embedded in a longer word of a phrase from list1.

Comment: @Paddy3118 I addressed the use-case you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is performance, you could store the elements of list2 in a prefix tree (or also called [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)).

Then you loop through all the elements *e* in list1 and then check for each position of *e* if you can find a substring in the prefix-tree that starts at said position.

The runtime of this should be O(|list1| * (max. wordlength from list1) ).

Of course this is kind of an overkill if the runtime is not a main concern for you. If possible, I would use a shorter solution.